# No values are copied from the default config

Tags: java, yaml, bukkit

I have written this code:

```
public void reloadDefConfig(File filepath, String fileInJar) {
    File configFile = filepath;
    FileConfiguration daConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);

    if (!configFile.exists()){
        log.info(logName + "Creating default \"" + fileInJar + "\".");

        InputStream defConfigStream = getResource(fileInJar);

        if (defConfigStream != null){
            YamlConfiguration defConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(defConfigStream);
            daConfig.setDefaults(defConfig);

            try {
                daConfig.save(configFile);
                log.info(logName + "Default config file \"" + fileInJar + "\" wrote.");
            } catch (IOException ex){
                log.severe(logName + "Could not write config file: " + fileInJar);
            }
        } else {
            log.warning(logName + "Could not find default \"" + fileInJar + "\" file.");
        }
    }
}
```

With the intent of taking this *config.yml* file inside the JAR and outputting it:

```
# Home section; this next part of code decides how large the radius to check for monsters
#  for the /home command if not set it will be auto default to 10x10x10 if you want to 
#  disable the radius use -1 on the value (note one value with -1 will disable all)
  home:
    x: 10
    y: 10
    x: 10
```

But when I call it like this:

```
reloadDefConfig(new File(getDataFolder(), "config.yml"), "config.yml");
```

No values are copied:

```
# Home section; this next part of code decides how large the radius to check for monsters
#  for the /home command if not set it will be auto default to 10x10x10 if you want to 
#  disable the radius use -1 on the value (note one value with -1 will disable all)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that you have two spaces before `home:`.
Try getting rid of them or adding a parent node, so the resulting file would look like this:

```
# Home section; this next part of code decides how large the radius to check for monsters
#  for the /home command if not set it will be auto default to 10x10x10 if you want to 
#  disable the radius use -1 on the value (note one value with -1 will disable all)
Main:
  home:
    x: 10
    y: 10
    x: 10
```